# lsmeans vs. differences between lsmeans

Tags: r, statistical-significance, standard-error, lme4-nlme

I calculated the least-squares means and standard errors for a linear mixed model. I am attempting to plot the lsmeans and standard errors for the combinations of the two factors, but I notice a discrepancy in what is allegedly significant.

```
> library(lmerTest)

> print(summary(data_dist))
   ID        interface    direction    error_dist      
12     : 18   fs     :108   depth :72   Min.   :-0.34375  
13     : 18   none   :108   height:72   1st Qu.:-0.13037  
14     : 18   RW_none:  0   width :72   Median :-0.04048  
15     : 18                             Mean   :-0.03464  
16     : 18                             3rd Qu.: 0.06022  
17     : 18                             Max.   : 0.36864  
(Other):108

> print(summary(model_error_dist))
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['merModLmerTest']
Formula: error_dist ~ direction * interface + (1 | ID) + (1 | ID:direction) 
Data: data_master 

REML criterion at convergence: -320.9162 

Random effects:
Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev.
ID:direction (Intercept) 0.005864 0.07658 
ID           (Intercept) 0.003395 0.05827 
Residual                 0.008463 0.09199 
Number of obs: 216, groups: ID:direction, 36; ID, 12

Fixed effects:
                                Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)                     0.019411   0.031728  35.080000   0.612   0.5446  
directionheight                -0.074568   0.038046  31.210000  -1.960   0.0590 .
directionwidth                 -0.058316   0.038046  31.210000  -1.533   0.1354  
interfacenone                  -0.037312   0.021683 176.810000  -1.721   0.0870 .
directionheight:interfacenone  -0.008412   0.030664 176.810000  -0.274   0.7841  
directionwidth:interfacenone    0.061797   0.030664 176.810000   2.015   0.0454 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) drctnh drctnw intrfc drctnh:
directnhght -0.600                             
directnwdth -0.600  0.500                      
interfacenn -0.342  0.285  0.285               
drctnhght:n  0.242 -0.403 -0.201 -0.707        
drctnwdth:n  0.242 -0.201 -0.403 -0.707  0.500 

> st <- step(model_error_dist)

> print(st)

Random effects:
                   Chi.sq Chi.DF elim.num p.value
(1 | ID)             3.28      1     kept    0.07
(1 | ID:direction)  37.83      1     kept  <1e-07

Fixed effects:
                    Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F.value elim.num Pr(>F)
direction           0.0446  0.0223     2  22.00  2.6379     kept 0.0940
interface           0.0206  0.0206     1 176.81  2.4308     kept 0.1208
direction:interface 0.0529  0.0265     2 176.81  3.1263     kept 0.0463

Least squares means:
                                 direction interface Estimate Standard Error   DF t-value Lower CI Upper CI p-value   
direction  depth                       1.0        NA   0.0008         0.0298 27.4    0.03  -0.0604   0.0619  0.9800   
direction  height                      2.0        NA  -0.0780         0.0298 27.4   -2.62  -0.1392  -0.0169  0.0143 * 
direction  width                       3.0        NA  -0.0267         0.0298 27.4   -0.89  -0.0878   0.0345  0.3790   
interface  fs                           NA       1.0  -0.0249         0.0229 12.8   -1.09  -0.0744   0.0246  0.2971   
interface  none                         NA       2.0  -0.0444         0.0229 12.8   -1.94  -0.0939   0.0051  0.0747 . 
direction:interface  depth fs          1.0       1.0   0.0194         0.0317 35.1    0.61  -0.0450   0.0838  0.5446   
direction:interface  height fs         2.0       1.0  -0.0552         0.0317 35.1   -1.74  -0.1196   0.0092  0.0909 . 
direction:interface  width fs          3.0       1.0  -0.0389         0.0317 35.1   -1.23  -0.1033   0.0255  0.2283   
direction:interface  depth none        1.0       2.0  -0.0179         0.0317 35.1   -0.56  -0.0823   0.0465  0.5762   
direction:interface  height none       2.0       2.0  -0.1009         0.0317 35.1   -3.18  -0.1653  -0.0365  0.0031 **
direction:interface  width none        3.0       2.0  -0.0144         0.0317 35.1   -0.45  -0.0788   0.0500  0.6523   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 Differences of LSMEANS:
                                             Estimate Standard Error    DF t-value Lower CI Upper CI p-value   
direction depth-height                            0.1         0.0348  22.0    2.26   0.0066   0.1510   0.034 * 
direction depth-width                             0.0         0.0348  22.0    0.79  -0.0448   0.0996   0.439   
direction height-width                           -0.1         0.0348  22.0   -1.47  -0.1236   0.0209   0.154   
interface fs-none                                 0.0         0.0125 176.8    1.56  -0.0052   0.0442   0.121   
direction:interface  depth fs- height fs          0.1         0.0380  31.2    1.96  -0.0030   0.1521   0.059 . 
direction:interface  depth fs- width fs           0.1         0.0380  31.2    1.53  -0.0193   0.1359   0.135   
direction:interface  depth fs- depth none         0.0         0.0217 176.8    1.72  -0.0055   0.0801   0.087 . 
direction:interface  depth fs- height none        0.1         0.0380  31.2    3.16   0.0427   0.1979   0.004 **
direction:interface  depth fs- width none         0.0         0.0380  31.2    0.89  -0.0437   0.1114   0.381   
direction:interface  height fs- width fs          0.0         0.0380  31.2   -0.43  -0.0938   0.0613   0.672   
direction:interface  height fs- depth none        0.0         0.0380  31.2   -0.98  -0.1148   0.0403   0.335   
direction:interface  height fs- height none       0.0         0.0217 176.8    2.11   0.0029   0.0885   0.036 * 
direction:interface  height fs- width none        0.0         0.0380  31.2   -1.07  -0.1183   0.0368   0.292   
direction:interface  width fs- depth none         0.0         0.0380  31.2   -0.55  -0.0986   0.0566   0.585   
direction:interface  width fs- height none        0.1         0.0380  31.2    1.63  -0.0156   0.1396   0.113   
direction:interface  width fs- width none         0.0         0.0217 176.8   -1.13  -0.0673   0.0183   0.260   
direction:interface  depth none- height none      0.1         0.0380  31.2    2.18   0.0054   0.1606   0.037 * 
direction:interface  depth none- width none       0.0         0.0380  31.2   -0.09  -0.0811   0.0741   0.928   
direction:interface  height none- width none     -0.1         0.0380  31.2   -2.27  -0.1640  -0.0089   0.030 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Final model:
lme4::lmer(formula = error_dist ~ direction + interface + (1 | 
    ID) + (1 | ID:direction) + direction:interface, data = data_master, 
    REML = reml, contrasts = l)
```

Plotting the lsmeans and standard errors gives me this graph:
[image: plot of least-squares means and standard errors]

From this plot, I can see that my standard error is huge and most comparisons between means will likely be insignificant. However, in the "Differences of LSMEANS" section of the output above, I see four significant differences.

This one I expect, based on the plot above:

```
direction:interface  depth fs- height none        0.1         0.0380  31.2    3.16   0.0427   0.1979   0.004 **
```

This one, for example, surprises me:

```
direction:interface  height fs- height none       0.0         0.0217 176.8    2.11   0.0029   0.0885   0.036 *
```

It seems I don't actually understand what these outputs are telling me. Can somebody please explain the reason for this discrepancy? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is due to familywise error rate (FWER).

In multiple comparison tests you need to control FWER, for example by using conservative Bonferroni correction. In `lmerTest` this is not included (probably will be in the near future), but you may use the `p.adjust` function in order to create adjusted p-values.

If I am not wrong, in your case you have 15 comparisons of `direction:interface`. So by using the Bonferroni correction, the adjusted p-value for direction:interface  height fs- height none becomes 0.036*15=0.54

Comment: I had wondered about this. I guess I didn't figure the problem would be this large. I think you might be right though.